# Avoid Xtext multiple alternatives warnings

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, emf, ecore

in my xtext dsl i have defined the following rules:

```
Port returns tdg::Port:
    'port'
    'kind' kind=Kind
    'type' type=Type;

enum Kind returns tdg::PortKind:
    In='in' | Out='out';

enum Type returns tdg::PortType:
    Numeric | String | Boolean | Tuple;
```

The tdg classes come frome an ecore model.
I get the following warnings when i compile the dsl grammar. How can i avoid them?

> warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/parser/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:250:1:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'String'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/parser/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:250:1:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Boolean'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/parser/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:250:1:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Tuple'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/parser/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:250:1:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Numeric'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl.ui/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:854:30:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Numeric'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl.ui/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:854:30:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'String'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl.ui/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:854:30:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Boolean'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input warning(200):
>   ../com.isax.testdatagen.dsl.ui/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/ui/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g:854:30:
>   Decision can match input such as "'port' 'kind' 'in' 'type' 'Tuple'"
>   using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were
>   disabled for that input

Comment: can you please share a complete reproducable grammar

Comment: You have a complete grammar when you add the following initial rule: Model: ports+=Port*;

Comment: this make the grammar still not ambigous. there must be something else in your grammar that causes the problem. without beeing able to reproduce i cannot help

Comment: There is nothing more. I think it is important that "tdg::Port", "tdg::PortKind", "tdg::PortType, "In|Out" and "Numeric|String|Boolean|Tuple" comes from an ecore model.

Comment: can you share the relevant parts of the ecore as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of "multiple alternatives" warning may be caused by a rule that is reachable using two "paths" of alternatives, e.g.

```
Model:
    Rule1a | Rule1b;

Rule1a:
    Rule2 | Rule1b;

Rule1b:
    {Rule1b} 'rule1b';

Rule2: 
    {Rule2} 'rule2';
```

Here, `rule1b` is reachable from the rule "Model" using two paths: Directly from "Model" and indirectly through "Rule1a".

As Christian stated, your error message cannot possibly be caused by the rules you listed. If your grammar contains only `Model: ports+=Port*;` apart from these, maybe you are generating a different grammar than you think you are?

In any case, to find the cause of the problem, you have  to identify the rule which has ambiguous instances: Open `com.isax.testdatagen.dsl/src-gen/com/isax/testdatagen/parser/antlr/internal/InternalTdgDSL.g` line 250 (as printed in the log) and find out which rule it belongs to. In my example, the error lies in the Antlr rule `ruleModel`, which corresponds to the Xtext rule `Model`.